# Destructor (__del__) called before initialization (__init__) complete

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructor

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("HEYYYYYYYYYY") # prints
        file = open("really_cool_file.txt")
        print("HOOOOOOOOOOOO") # does **NOT** print
        self._f = file
        print("WADUP!!!!!!!!!!") # does **NOT** print
        print(hasattr(self, "_f"))

    def __del__(self):
        print("closing any open files ")
        self._f.close()


my_instance = MyClass()
print("33333333333") # NEVER PRINTS
```

The console output is as follows:

```
HEYYYYYYYYYY
closing any open files
```

We receive the following error message:

```
C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe 
H:/PYTHON_RECORD_VIDEO/dffhsrthrth.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/PYTHON_RECORD_VIDEO/dffhsrthrth.py", line 15, in <module>

    my_instance = MyClass()

  File "H:/PYTHON_RECORD_VIDEO/dffhsrthrth.py", line 4, in __init__
    file = open("really_cool_file.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'really_cool_file.txt'
Exception ignored in: <function MyClass.__del__ at 0x0383D1D8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/PYTHON_RECORD_VIDEO/dffhsrthrth.py", line 12, in __del__
    self._f.close()
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '_f'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The destructor is called before the line `self._f = file` ever happens inside of `__init__`
I do not understand how the destructor could be called before `__init__` is finished executing.

Comment: Beware of using `__del__`; it isn't guaranteed to be called if your object is deleted because the interpreter is exiting, as is the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `open` call is failing; the exception causes the rest of `__init__` to be skipped (it bubbles straight out without executing the rest of the initializer), but `__init__` is just the initializer, not the constructor, so `__del__` must still be invoked when the object is cleaned up. Since you failed to assign to `self._f`, the finalizer fails to find it.

Exceptions raised in `__del__` are logged and ignored (because they don't occur predictably, so there is no safe way to handle them), so this won't break your program, so long as the exception from opening the file is caught and handled.

If you want to be resilient against this scenario (to avoid the second error message), just make `__del__` more resilient:

```
def __del__(self):
    print("closing any open files ")
    try:
        self._f.close()
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # Exception in constructor won't initialize _f; ignore it
```

Comment: `file = open("really_cool_file.txt")` raises an exception, and the exception goes unhandled. I would think that if an exception is not caught, the program would immediately terminate. There is no need to loop over each variable, de-allocating memory for each. If a program terminates, then all of the memory assigned to that program it becomes free. What is absolutely bizarre, is that if an exception is raised, and the exception is not caught, it looks like python will go around deleting every piece of data in the program. `__del__` gets called, which raises a **NEW** exception.

Comment: If there is an unhandled exception, the program should **STOP** The program should **terminate** -- immediately. If you catch the exception, then yes, things keep happening, but if you do not catch the exception, then the program should stop. I don't understand why python does alot of clean-up (including calling `__del__` for each an every item still in the program) AFTER an exception goes unhandled.

Comment: Suppose that there are 3 variables in the workspace when the program crashes. Once the program stops running, the operating systems frees all memory that was reserved for that program, including the 3 variables. The workspace that did exist, exists no longer. There is absolutely no need for python to delete all remaining/leftover data in the workspace before the operating systems deletes it all anyway.

Comment: I can't believe this. 1) An error occurred. 2) python decided to "close" everything that was currently "open" (I am using the words "open" and "close" loosely here) 3) an error occurred when python was closing things down. That makes no sense. Imagine a computer program as a person having papers spread out all over their desk. When a program "terminates," the operating system will take every single paper on the desk, and sweep them into a trash bin. There is no need for python to throw away it's paper notes beforehand. When a program dies, all of its memory goes with it.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: You're missing the purpose here. Freeing memory is (as you note) pointless; the OS reclaims it automatically. But not all program state is transient; properly closing files (and flushing data still in user mode buffers), deleting open `NamedTemporaryFile`s, executing arbitrary `finally` blocks where some external state is manipulated and correctness requires it to execute, etc. is stuff people *like* to happen; it's not necessary, but it's helpful. I'll note that exceptions raised in `__del__` are logged, but ignored, because there is no useful way to respond to them.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: So while the dump from `__del__`'s exception is ugly, it's also harmless (the original exception is the only one bubbling and being handled). Yes, low level languages like C++ generally go with "there was an exception? BURN IT DOWN!", but there's nothing intrinsically terrible about *trying* to conduct an orderly shutdown even when stuff is on fire.

Comment: To be clear: Everything in Python is built around these exception behaviors. `finally` blocks are actually reliable because even stuff like `sys.exit()` is implemented in terms of exceptions (it's equivalent to `raise SystemExit()`, it's just when it bubbles all the way up, the default unhandled exception handler handles it silently). `__del__` is frowned upon (because it's not reliable on non-CPython interpreters; `with` statement context managers are the preferred solution), but since it's historically been semi-reliable, CPython makes a best effort attempt to handle it "nicely".